# Twisted Whitehead double of trefoil knot

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, knot-theory

Let $K$ be a knot whose Alexander polynomial is not trivial and $G = \pi_1(S^3-K)$. By Tim Cochran's noncommutative theory, $G$ is not solvable. But is $G$ a hypoabelian group? In particular, I'm interested in twisted Whitehead doubles of trefoil knot $K'$. Is it possible that the transfinite derived series of $\pi_1(S^3 - K')$ terminates at a nontrivial perfect core at stage $\omega$, where $\omega$ is a limit ordinal? A related question is, can $G_H^{(\omega)}$ be trivial, where $G_H^{(\omega)}$ is the torsion-free derived series developed by Harvey?